# How do you return an enum as the mocked expectation with JMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

My test requires that one of the dependent mocked methods returns an enum.  However, this causes JMockit to throw a ClassCastException.

```
public class MyTest {

    @Mocked Parameters params;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        new NonStrictExpectation() {
            {
                params.getPlatform(); result = Platform.DESKTOP;
            }
        };
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(params);
        String str = myClass.run();

        assertNotNull(str);
    }
}
```

Running the test throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mypackage.Platform
```

How do I properly return an enum?

Comment: What's the return type of `run()`?

Comment: run() would return String, but internally run() calls params.getPlatform which returns Platfrom.

Comment: The test works fine for me (with minimal definitions for `Parameters`, `Platform`, and `MyClass`). Can you show a more complete example?